# 3 Spinners not working

Tags: java, android, spinner, adapter

I have this problem: 3 spinners (2 of them shows the same information and its ok) but the 3rd (car information) is not. It's showing the same information as the other two ones.

```
public class AlterarEquipeActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private Spinner tecnico_altera1;
private Spinner tecnico_altera2;
private Spinner carro;


  @Override
  protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_alterar_equipe);

    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter =

            ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
                    this, R.array.tecnico_altera,
                    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    tecnico_altera1 = findViewById(R.id.tecnico_altera1);
    tecnico_altera1.setAdapter(adapter);

    ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
            this, R.array.tecnico_altera,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    tecnico_altera2 = findViewById(R.id.tecnico_altera2);
    tecnico_altera2.setAdapter(adapter);

    ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
            this, R.array.carro,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    carro = findViewById(R.id.carro);
    carro.setAdapter(adapter);


  }


  public void AlterarActivity (View view) {
  }


  public void showText (View view) {
  }
```

Comment: please share the output snapshot also

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are *setting the same adapter to all*.

change it as,

```
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
                    this, R.array.tecnico_altera,
                    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    tecnico_altera1 = findViewById(R.id.tecnico_altera1);
    tecnico_altera1.setAdapter(adapter);

     ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter2 =ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
            this, R.array.tecnico_altera,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    tecnico_altera2 = findViewById(R.id.tecnico_altera2);
    tecnico_altera2.setAdapter(adapter2);

     ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter3 =ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
            this, R.array.carro,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    carro = findViewById(R.id.carro);
    carro.setAdapter(adapter3);
```